# How to parse CustomWritable from text in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Say I have timestamped values for specific users in text files, like

```
#userid; unix-timestamp; value
1; 2010-01-01 00:00:00; 10
2; 2010-01-01 00:00:00; 20
1; 2010-01-01 01:00:00; 11
2; 2010-01-01 01:00:00, 21
1; 2010-01-02 00:00:00; 12
2; 2010-01-02 00:00:00; 22
```

I have a custom class "SessionSummary" implementing *readFields* and *write* of *WritableComparable*. It's purpose is to sum up all values per user for each calendar day.

So the mapper maps the lines to each user, the reducer summarizes all values per day per user and outputs a SessionSummary as TextOutputFormat (using *toString* of *SessionSummary*, as tab-separated UTF-8 strings):

```
1; 2010-01-01; 21
2; 2010-01-01; 41
1; 2010-01-02; 12
2; 2010-01-02; 22
```

If I need to use these summary-entries for a second Map/Reduce stage, how should I parse this summary data to populate the members? Can I reuse the existing readFields and write-methods (of the *WritableComparable* interface implementation) by using the text String as *DataInput* somehow? This (obviously) did not work:

```
public void map(...) {
    SessionSummary ssw = new SessionSummary();
    ssw.readFields(new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
}
```

**In general: Is there a best practice to implement custom keys and values in Hadoop and make them easily reusable across several M/R stages, while keeping human-readable text output at every stage?**

(Hadoop version is 0.20.2 / CDH3u3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output format for your first MR job should be `SequenceFileOutputFormat` - this will store the Key/Values output from the reducer in a binary format, that can then be read back in, in your second MR job using `SequenceFileInputFormat`. Also make sure you set the `outputKeyClass` and `outputValueClass` on the `Job` accordingly.

The mapper in the second job then has `SessionSummary` (and whatever the value type is)

If you need to see the textual output from the first MR job, you can run the following on the output files in HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -libjars my-lib.jar -text output-dir/part-r-*
```

This will read in the sequence file Key/Value pairs and call `toString()` on both objects, tab separating them when outputting to stdout. The `-libjars` specifies where hadoop can find your custom Key / Value classes

Comment: Thanks Chris! So for the second MR job, I set conf.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class), and the Mapper key and value classes are the same as in the output of the first Reducer, correct?

Comment: How do I explicitely set the Mapper key and value classes for the second MR job? I'm testing with IdentityMapper, and it expects Text as key.

Comment: Are you using the new or old API (mapred or mapreduce in the package name). I'm assuming from your question about IdentityMapper, the old API. Eitherway, they are generic classes, which should just output the types given to them. Probably best to take it offline from here - can you post your code somewhere (github or pastebin) and i'll take a more detailed look

Comment: Thanks again. I'm using the old API, the code is here: http://pastebin.com/d4fiT2xS 

The output of the SingleSessionSummarizer (1st MR) is meant to be the input of the MultiSessionSummarizer (2nd MR). 

For the 2nd MR, I only need the reduce-stage, so I thought I use IdentityMapper, but that gives me java.lang.ClassCastException: SessionSummaryWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Comment: in `MultiSessionSummarizer`, add two entries to define the output types of your map (like you have in `SingleSessionSummarizer`) - if you don't define them, hadoop will assume they are the same as the reduce output types, hence your error

Comment: With the new API you don't need to explicitly set the Map or Reduce class if you're using the Identity versions. The output key/value types always need to be set as @Chris White indicates. I'm pretty sure its the same with the older API.