# SequenceFile as text CLI with custom class

Tags: hadoop, command-line-interface, sequencefile

I have an HDFS file in `SequenceFile` format. The key is `Text` and the value is a custom serializable class (say) `MyCustomClass`. I want to read this file via the `hadoop fs -text` command but it fails as hadoop does not know what `MyCustomClass` definition is.

I also tried `hdfs dfs - text` command but got the same response back. Using hadoop2.

Is there a way I can specify the class (through a jar for example, like `-cp myjar.jar` option)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hadoop fs -libjars my-lib.jar -text output-dir/part-r-*
```

This will read in the sequence file Key/Value pairs and call toString() on both objects, tab separating them when outputting to stdout. The -libjars specifies where hadoop can find your custom Key / Value classes

[how-to-parse-customwritable-from-text-in-hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721754/how-to-parse-customwritable-from-text-in-hadoop)

Comment: Funny. I had tried `hadoop fs -text <hdfs_file> -libjars <jar>` but didn't try `-libjars` option first :D

Answer (score 1):

You can add the jar containing the custom writable class using `-libjars`.

For example:

`hadoop fs -libjars <JAR>.jar -text <DIR>`